# Share Sheet does not include my app when building for device, but it does in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, share-extension

When I build my app for a device with xcode, the app does not show up in the share sheet. However, when I build and run it on the simulator the app does show up in the share sheet.

I added the share extension to my xcode project. I tried modifying my info.plist for the share extension to include specific types, but this does not resolve the issue:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

Also, if I run it as a desktop app, I am able to enable sharing and it shows up as in the mac share sheet:

[desktop app share sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G2MK.png)